# Exp:resso Store: how to handle products requiring a deposit?

Tags: expressionengine, add-on, expresso-store

How can I set up Store product entries to require an initial deposit and then request a final amount at a later date?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this using built in functionality. However, there are a couple ways you can achieve it:

- Create a promo code/discount for say 90% off the order (leave the "code" blank and it will automatically apply to all orders). In your template, make it clear that the discounted amount is a "deposit", and that you will ask for the remainder later.
- Write a PHP extension to calculate your deposit and update the cart during checkout.

With the first option, there is no easy/automatic way to claim the remainder of the order (since Store thinks it has already been fully paid).

The most flexible option is to write a simple extension to only require a deposit during checkout, and once the order has been created, you should also be able to use standard functionality to claim the rest of the payment (your customers would still need to enter their credit card details again though, as these are not stored).